# We cannot convert a value of type Function to Type Table when invoking custom function

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have the following code for a function:

```
let HighFunction = (InTable as table) =>
let Source = InTable,
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Table.PromoteHeaders",1),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Top Rows"),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Transposed Table",{"Column1"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Column1] = "Cashflows by Tranche")),
    #"Filled Down1" = Table.FillDown(#"Filtered Rows",{"Column2"}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down1", each ([Column3] <> null)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Column1"}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if [Index] = 0 then "Tranche" else [Column2]),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index", "Column2"}),
    #"Promoted Headers1" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Columns1", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Promoted Headers1", each ([Date] <> "Date")),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Filtered Rows2", {"Date", "Tranche"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Date]), "Date", "Value", List.Sum),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Attribute", "Period End Date"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
in HighFunction
```

When I attempt to invoke this function on a table (of the correct format) as follows:

```
= HighFunction(#"inpTable")
```

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred in the ‘HighFunction’ query. Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Function to type Table.
Details:
    Value=[Function]
    Type=[Type]
```

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Table.PromoteHeaders",1)
```

needs to be

```
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Promoted Headers",1)
```

since **Table.PromoteHeaders** was the last function used, but **#"Promoted Headers"** is the last step name and for each row, you need to specify the step name you want to work on, not the prior function name

If there are similar errors in prior step names, change those in the rest of the code